# Activity.finish() called but activity stays loaded in memory

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

When I run my app on the debugger, I get the main thread and 3 binder threads.

On a button click I call **Activity.finish()**, which looks like it ends the activity as the UI closes and goes back to the home screen.

However, in the debugger, it still shows the main thread and 3 binder threads as "*(running)*".

I am baffled to why this is happening. Even more so, it is causing my app to call **Activity.onResume()** when I run it again after exiting the app.

I currently override these methods in the Activity, but I call the appropriate super functions in each one:

- onDestroy()
- onPause()
- onResume()
- onSaveInstanceState()

Any help or advice regarding this is much appreciated!

Comment: Read about the activity lifecycle. And understand this http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/app/doc-files/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: Hi Fiction, I've read the documentation many times and the image you posted was where I got my understanding from. I was just confused to see that it was resuming rather than restarting after I called Activity.finish().

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't control when your app leaves main memory, the OS does. Look closely at [Activity.finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)...

> Call this when your activity is done
>   and should be closed. The
>   ActivityResult is propagated back to
>   whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

Note that is says nothing about memory. As to calling Activity.onResume, that's exactly what you would expect for the lifecycle; remeber that onResume is not just called after a resume but even when the app is first launched after onCreate.

While not exactly what you asked I suggest you read [this article about exit buttons](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html) which goes on to say something very important

> **[Activity.finish] is exactly equivalent to hitting the back button.**

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew, that was a bit of a mind opener. I've always been thinking that Activity.finish() closes it rather than puts it on the queue for closure. Gotta do some rework in that case.